# Single Page Application on embedded systems

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, javascript-framework

I am working on a project where we are running our web server on an embedded system so I have memory constraints but is there a way for me to build a Single Page Application on this web server ? If, yes then do we have a javascript framework that I can work with or am I stuck with basic javascript itself ?

And there will be real time data sent and received from the server.

Comment: Memory constraints on server  shouldn't affect front end ... javascript runs in browser. Should be able to use any framework you want. Try one and come back when you run into real code problems

Comment: Right now I have constraints to even store a minified Bootstrap file on the device. So the node modules of react should take up significant memory ("disk space") on my device. I still feel few havent got my question.

Comment: You don't need node modules. A single page app can be served as static html, js & css and you could use cdn resources for libraries

Comment: Storing your front end file in a CDN would be a solution, if your user have access to Internet, but can you give use more information about your embedded system configuration? are you running an operating system on it?

Comment: You guys have no idea what you are talking about. This is about embedded applications where you are generally running very low capacity microprocessors. It's very different than web development. Embedded applications are meant to be locally contained applications that only expose data to the internet through an API. There are no CDN's and both memory and processor capacities are major driving factors in development

Comment: @WaelBoutglay Its runs on RTOS which is pretty basic with multiple threads. But I do have an option of SD card which I got to know just now.

Comment: A suitable solution would probably be a minimal HTML page with only a link to an externally stored Javascript script that will initialize the page and load other resources (CSS, JS... stored also in a external CDN); the size of the page will be (102 Bytes + length of the URI to the JS script) stored in a buffer in your application program that you will deliver to the user via http/tcp setup.

Comment: I understand i'm commenting on very old issue. But just to add to this, actually memory constraints for embedded device comes into picture if you want to store all frontend files on embedded device memory ..this is mostly because user connects to embedded device directly (device working as a Access point or connected through LAN without internet). But if this is not the case and still you want a cool looking front end then its best idea to develop a REST API at server on embedded device and only expose json api endpoints. Keep entire frontend (Angular, Vue) on any client device.

Answer (score 1):

Single-page applications can have very little logic on the server-side, since the entire application is JavaScript that is run on the client. The only server-side logic you will absolutely need will be a small server that sends the files to the client (which would the the web browser in which you're accessing the site).

As mentioned before by Gerton, you can comfortably build a SPA with Angular. You can also look at the other two of the most used frameworks currently: react.js and vue.js.

Have fun!

Comment: Yeah I did read that Vue can be used for embedded servers. Will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Seems to support your question quite nicely, it's a single page application framework

Answer (score 0):

I work on multiple embedded systems and would recommend re-architecting your solution. The whole web server to UI concept for embedded systems is the old way of doing things and it's not the fastest or the most efficient for generating real time data. You should be looking into QT for Linux-based systems or Xamarin for Windows based systems.

If you already have the back-end data model finished, it's easy to create a new project in one of these applications and build a UI over the top. Trust me on this one. It'll save you a ton of hassle and will increase the performance of your embedded system.

If you implement a web server, I would recommend doing it to expose data to a cloud application or as part of a distributed architecture, not part of feeding data to your local UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But cant expose the data to a cloud application its a constraint. I will have to feed it to the UI itself.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm saying get rid of the server and use QT or Xamarin for your user interface. What is your back end programmed in?

Comment: Backend is C++. We are using Mongoose embedded server.

Comment: I would look into QT compatibility. I'm not sure how well it would play with RTOS but it works well with Linux. One of the applications I work on has a C++ backend and a QML front end all programmed in QT. The entire application uses less than 20% of a 1.6 Ghz embedded microprocessor.

Comment: Contrast that with another application that uses an Angular front end and spikes at 80-100% of the processor every time we poll for data on a 1.7 Ghz microprocessor.

Comment: Its a 180 MHz arm cortex-m4 processor.. so its not that powerful... So is it wise to use frameworks at all ? Because this is something I am doing for the first time. I have worked mostly on webservers which run on PC's and have a lot of memory and processing.

Comment: How complex is your application? How many data points are you polling for and how often?

Comment: Also, what RTOS are you using? What's your operating system?

Comment: The application is quite complicated it has to talk to around 50 devices connected to it and poll from them. And polling will be done every 3 secs. Cmsis is the RTOS we are using.

Comment: how much of the processor are you using up with your current application?